# Caching image thumbnail web-application based on rocket

Tags: image, file-system, rust

This is my first rocket web-app. It serves images from a directory and thumbnails from a sub-directory. if no thumbnail is found for an existing image it is created on the fly.

Before I launch this thing into production/space, it would be calming to have some experts' eyes on it and be made aware of any glaring holes as well as things that would work, but can be optimized.

### Question

In particular I am not sure what happens, if the app is run in multiple workers and multiple requests to thumbnail the same image are handled simultaneously.

Would I have to place locks on files and how would i do that?

### Code

```rust
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
extern crate image;

use std::fs::File;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use rocket::{Request, response::content, response::NamedFile};
use self::image::{FilterType, JPEG};


const IMAGE_DIR: &str = "images/";


pub fn resize_and_crop_to(filename: &PathBuf, cached: &PathBuf, width: u32, height: u32) -> Option<()> {
    let i = image::open(filename);
    match i {
        Ok(img) => {
            let scaled = img.resize_to_fill(width, height, FilterType::CatmullRom);
            let mut output = File::create(cached).expect("Could not open cache file");
            scaled.write_to(&mut output, JPEG).ok()
        },
        Err(_error) => None
    }
}

pub fn get_filename(name: &str) -> PathBuf {
    let filename: PathBuf = [ IMAGE_DIR, name ].iter().collect();
    filename
}

pub fn get_cache_filename(name: &str, format: &str) -> PathBuf {
    let filename = [ IMAGE_DIR, format, name ].iter().collect();
    filename
}

#[get("/<image>")]
fn original(image: String) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    let filename = get_filename(image.as_str());
    NamedFile::open(filename.as_os_str()).ok()
}

#[get("/thumb/<image>")]
fn scaled(image: String) -> Option<NamedFile> {
    let format = "thumb";
    let cached = get_cache_filename(image.as_str(), format);
    let f = NamedFile::open(&cached);
    match f {
        Ok(file) => Some(file),
        Err(_error) => {
            let filename = get_filename(image.as_str());
            resize_and_crop_to(&filename, &cached, 280, 180)?;
            NamedFile::open(cached).ok()
       }
    }
}

#[catch(404)]
fn not_found(request: &Request) -> content::Html<String> {
    let html = format!(
        "<p>{} not found</p>",
         request.uri()
    );
    content::Html(html)
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![original, scaled])
        .register(catchers![not_found])
        .launch();
}
```

(I could not add tags #rocket, nor #rust-rocket for lack of reputation points)